# Relay RISING triggers GPIO event detect on another pin

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, gpio

I'm working on two separate projects on my RPi, a relay that drives a lamp (on GPIO 22) and a button that reboots the RPi (on GPIO 23). They both work fine when run alone but if I try to access the pin 22 while the 23 is being monitored the 23 reads a RISING although I have NOT pressed the button.

Here's the code of the program running on 23:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
import os
import sys

def handler (signo):
   print ("Rebooting\n")
   GPIO.cleanup()
   os.system("sudo reboot")
   exit()


GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
pin = 23
GPIO.setup(pin, GPIO.IN,pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)


try:
   GPIO.add_event_detect(pin, GPIO.RISING, callback=handler, bouncetime=800)
while (1):
    time.sleep(10)

 except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print ("Quit")
    GPIO.cleanup()
```

**Here's a scheme of the circuit:**
[scheme.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K1DsR.jpg)

Does anyone know why this is happening?

I'm trying to access the gpio 22 (the relay) through:

```
/sys/class/gpio#...
```

Comment: relays are inductive by nature, its possible that it is generating flyback that is upsetting pin 23, you could try adding a flyback suppression diode (bypass diode) across the relay to prevent this. this page has a reasonable explanation: https://www.quora.com/In-a-relay-what-is-the-use-of-a-flyback-diode

Comment: The relay is part of a module like this: http://www.aliexpress.com/item/With-optocoupler-4-channel-4-channel-relay-modules-relay-control-panel-PLC-relay-5V-four-way/1952619257.html. So I think it already has a flyback diode. I tried adding another diode between the button and the ground but I still get unwanted RISING on the 23.

Comment: that looks like it has both a flyback diode and an opto isolator so that shouldn't be the problem.. have you tried using python to access GPIO22 aswell to see it that makes a difference?

Comment: Just tried with no luck :( The same behaviour.

Comment: can i suggest changing your button circuit slightly?the build in pull up resistors of any IC are usually pretty high resistance, it may be that noise is coupled across because of this. try using an external pull up resistor (as well as in the code) of a reasonable value (~4.7K - 10K) with the button acting as a hard short to ground and see if the behaves the same.

Comment: something similar to this (but with your pin numbers obv.) http://i.imgur.com/FqnNB.png

Comment: I have found a similar question: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/36413/is-it-normal-when-a-pin-goes-low-it-triggers-a-interrupt-on-an-another-one